# Boost not working over network

Tags: c++, boost

I've made a simple module for transferring data. Most of my code is based on [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599638/how-can-i-wrap-stdwstring-in-boostasiobuffer) I found on SO

When I run the instances on my local machine, everything works fine. But if I try running this over a local area network, I get the error "Can't Assign Requested Address".

Note: My "instances basically involve running ./server 1 0 and ./server 1 1 so, they;re waiting for data. And then ./server 0 to send it over.

Here's the code

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

static std::string const server_ip = "10.0.0.4";
static std::string const client_ip = "10.0.0.5";

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Location {
    double rent[6];
    double cost[7];
    std::string name, group;
    std::string locationOfObjectFile;
    int locationNo;

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned) {
        ar &rent;
        ar &cost;
        ar &name;
        ar &group;
        ar &locationOfObjectFile;
        ar &locationNo;
    }
};

struct Player {
    int currentPosition;
    double currentMoney;

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned) {
        ar &currentPosition;
        ar &currentMoney;
    }
};

struct Monopoly {
    std::vector<Location> locations;
    std::vector<Player> players;
    std::string currency;

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned) {
        ar &locations;
        ar &players;
        ar &currency;
    }
};

Location l1;
Player p1;
Monopoly game, game2;

void readData(int x) {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    uint16_t port = x;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(
        io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(server_ip), port));

    /* code */

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    acceptor.accept(socket);
    std::cout << "connection from " << socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

    // read header
    size_t header;
    boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(&header, sizeof(header)));
    std::cout << "body is " << header << " bytes" << std::endl;

    // read body
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    const size_t rc = boost::asio::read(socket, buf.prepare(header));
    buf.commit(header);
    std::cout << "read " << rc << " bytes" << std::endl;

    // deserialize
    std::istream is(&buf);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ar(is);
    ar &game2;

    cout << game2.locations[0].rent[1] << endl;
    cout << game2.players[0].currentPosition << "how cool is this?";
    socket.close();
}

void sendData() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        boost::asio::streambuf buf;
        std::ostream os(&buf);
        boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(os);
        ar &game;

        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        short port = i + 1234;
        socket.connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(client_ip), port));

        const size_t header = buf.size();
        std::cout << "buffer size " << header << " bytes" << std::endl;

        // send header and buffer using scatter
        std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
        buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(&header, sizeof(header)));
        buffers.push_back(buf.data());
        const size_t rc = boost::asio::write(socket, buffers);
        std::cout << "wrote " << rc << " bytes" << std::endl;
        ;
        socket.close();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    l1.name = "soemthig";
    l1.group = 2;
    p1.currentMoney = 300;
    p1.currentPosition = 422;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        l1.cost[i] = i;
        /* code */
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        l1.rent[i] = 2 * i;
        /* code */
    }
    l1.locationOfObjectFile = "ajhsdk/asdc.obj";
    l1.locationNo = 5;
    game.locations.push_back(l1);
    game.players.push_back(p1);
    game.currency = "dollar";
    cout << game.currency;
    if (atoi(argv[1]) ==
        1) // argv[0]=0 implies server, argv[0]==1 implies client while argv[1] specifies 1st or second client
    {
        cout << "reading data";

        if (atoi(argv[2]) == 0) {
            readData(1234);
            /* code */
        } else {
            readData(1235);
        }

    } else {
        cout << "writing data";
        sendData();
    }
}
```

Here is the error message stack trace:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector‌​<boost::system::system_error> >: bind: Can't assign requested address dollarreading dataAbort trap: 6 and 10.0.0.4 is the IP address of the computer that is supposed to send the data.
```

Comment: Here's the entire error(it's a runtime error, so no line numbers)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >: bind: Can't assign requested address
dollarreading dataAbort trap: 6

and 10.0.0.4 is the IP address of the computer that is supposed to send the data.

Comment: It seems that your IP address 10.0.0.4 is of your machine. Didn't you want the IP address of the other machine to be there? Check the error message. Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: You're readin it wrong. The machine which threw the error was 10.0.0.5. The other one was 10.0.0.4

Comment: Because I haven't use this functionality, it is taking me longer to fix this. But I would've thought you needed some port number to go with it. Also, isn't there any authentication required? Also, check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882566/boostasio-ipv4-address-and-udp-comms.

Comment: I've made your code self contained and **[running live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd1844052658cc99)**. Please do this; making your code selfcontained make it possible for people to actually fix things.

Answer (score 0):

You get this when the connection is refused.

This, in turn, could happen when the client is not listening on the required interface.

Make sure that the IP addresses are actually the public IP addresses on the network and the machines can reach eachother. E.g. use `netstat -tlpn` (or similar on your OS) to ascertain that the clients *are* listening:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.136:1234      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18186/valgrind.bin
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.136:1235      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18187/valgrind.bin
```

Now, try to connect using e.g. netcat from the server machine:

```
netcat 192.168.2.136 1234
```

This will probably crash the client, but it will also tell you whether connecting was possible.

If not, then either the address is not reachable, the client is not listening on the right interface, the firewall is filtering your traffic etc.

---

PS. I've made your code self contained and running **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd1844052658cc99)**. Please do this; making your code selfcontained make it possible for people to actually fix things

Comment: I have a question. I'm planning to place this function inside a GLUT display function. Will boost make this work asynchronously by default? Or will I have to change my code?